# Multiply span text based on radio button and Jquery slider selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put together a selection flow for a product, and I am having a slight issue with defining a value.

Essentially what I am trying to do is have a total output based on which option they choose which is multiplied by the amount of lines. I'm not sure on how to do this however as the slider doesn't go up in regular increments.

```js
$("#slider").slider(
    {
        value:1,
        min: 0,
        max: 9,
        step: 1,
    }
);

var items =[ '1 <br>line','2 <br>lines','3 <br>lines','4 <br>lines','5 <br>lines','8 <br>lines','10 <br>lines','15 <br>lines','20+ <br>lines'];

var s = $("#slider");

s.slider({
  min:1,
  max:items.length
});

var oneBig = 100 / (items.length - 1);

$.each(items, function(key,value){
  var w = oneBig;
  if(key === 0 || key === items.length-1)
    w = oneBig/2;
    
  $("#legend").append("<label style='width: "+w+"%'>"+value+"</laben>");  
  
});



//sum start ///////////////



$(":radio").on("change", function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(){
        total += Number(this.value);
    });
    
   $("#total").text(total);
});
```

```css
h3 {
  margin-top:30px;
}

#slider label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

.lines {
    font-size:10px;
  
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight:bold;
}
label:first-child {
    text-align:left;
}
label:last-child {
    text-align:right;
}

.slide-col #slider a {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #1b2a3d;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="5.99" />option 1
<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="9.99" />option 2
<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="7.99" />option 3


<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>

<br>

<h3>Your total is: £<span id="total">0.00</span></h3>
```

Comment: I guess you want to update the total based on the slider movement. If yes, you'll need to attach onchange handler for slider too and then multiply by the radio selected.

Comment: Hi Anurag, thank you for the suggestion. I'm still unsure on how to multiply based on the slider value, as the increments that I need are not consistent.

Comment: See updated answer which includes changes via radio and slider both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** You may customize slider's values. Also adding function to calculate total value.

```js
let $slider = $('#slider'),
    $legend = $('#legend'),
    $total = $('#total'),
    total = 0, 
    lines = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20];

lines.forEach( (value, key) => {
  let oneBig = 100 / (lines.length - 1);
  let width = (key === 0 || key === lines.length -1) ? 
              oneBig / 2 : oneBig;
  let text = (key !== lines.length - 1) ?
              value + ' <br>lines' : value + '+ <br>lines';
  let label = $('<label/>')
                .css({ 'width': width + '%'})
                .html(text);
  $legend.append(label);
});

$(":radio").on("change", function(){
  updateTotal(lines[$slider.slider("option", "value")]);
});

$slider.slider({
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 8,
  step: 1,
  create: () => {
    updateTotal(lines[$slider.slider('value')]);
  },
  slide: (events, ui) => {
    updateTotal(lines[ui.value]);
  }
});

function updateTotal (value) {
  total = value * $("input[name='phone']:checked").val();
  $total.text(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#slider label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.lines {
    font-size:10px;
  
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight:bold;
}
label:first-child {
    text-align:left;
}
label:last-child {
    text-align:right;
}

.slide-col #slider a {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #1b2a3d;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="5.99" checked/>option 1
<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="9.99" />option 2
<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="7.99" />option 3


<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>

<br>

<h3>Your total is: £<span id="total">0.00</span></h3>
```

Comment: Spot on! this is exactly what I am looking for! thank you

Comment: Your very welcome. It also improve performance in your code too.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/b64Ug/224/
if you notice, I have attached the 'slide' attribute to your slider which will be invoked every time the slider value changed. You may want to add some checks for the edge cases.

```
$("#slider").slider(
    {
        value:1,
        min: 0,
        max: 9,
        step: 1,
    }
);
var valueMap = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20];

var items =[ '1 <br>line','2 <br>lines','3 <br>lines','4 <br>lines','5 <br>lines','8 <br>lines','10 <br>lines','15 <br>lines','20+ <br>lines'];

var s = $("#slider");

s.slider({
  min:1,
  max:items.length,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#total").text("$" +  (valueMap[ui.value] * $('input[name=phone]:checked').val()));
      }
});

var oneBig = 100 / (items.length - 1);

$.each(items, function(key,value){
  var w = oneBig;
  if(key === 0 || key === items.length-1)
    w = oneBig/2;

  $("#legend").append("<label style='width: "+w+"%'>"+value+"</laben>");  

});



//sum start ///////////////



$(":radio").on("change", function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(){
        total = Number(this.value) * valueMap[Number($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ))];
    });

   $("#total").text(total);
});
```

Comment: Hi Anurag Thank you but this still doesn't cater for the custom values in the slider (ie it doesnt just go up in increments of 1. After 5 the increments jump up in value)

Comment: I still didn't get it. Could you use some data from your sample and explain in some more detail? Especially on what is expected and what it shows

Comment: I can see the slider move by 1 step i.e from 0 to 9, 1 step at a time. Do you want to have some custom values such as 1.5 in the slider?

Comment: Essentially what I am looking for is custom values. So the radio value is muliplied by the amount of lines. For example, if the customer chose option one and 8 lines, the total would be 47.92 (£5.99 x 8). This isn't working as of yet as the slider is only going up by 1 each time. After the 5th step the value jumps up by 3 rather than 1. The values in the slider need to be : 1,2,3,4,5,8,10,15,20 however they still need to stop at regular intervals to match up with the label

Comment: I get it now, I think you can have a map where key is the slider values 1..9 and it's corresponding value will be the actual value you want. so for 6 value will be 8. You pick the value from slider, get it's corresponding value from map and then use it.

Comment: Updated answer, refer link above or access http://jsfiddle.net/b64Ug/224/  Look for valueMap variable that's added now